# how to find character from linked list pointer character

Tags: c++

So I need to delete a character from a linked list. However, the normal way (data->c==val) does not seem to work here.

This is my struct:

```
struct ll {
    char *c = new char;
    ll *prev;
    ll *next;
};
```

This is my character pointer that I need to find:

```
char *x=new char[1];
x[0]='R';
x[1]='\0';
```

This is the function I want to use to delete the linked list with this character:

```
void del(ll *data, char *val) {
    ll *temp, *temp2;
    bool sm = false;
    char * x = val;
    while (data != nullptr) {
        if (data->prev == nullptr) {
            if (data->c == x) {
                temp = data;
                data = data->next;
                data->prev = nullptr;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (data->c == x) {
                temp = data;
                data = data->prev;
                data->next = temp->next;
                temp2 = data->next;
                temp2->prev = data;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        data = data->next;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like the if statement doesn't work correctly whenever I compare the two characters. I took the linked list from a file so does that have anything to do with it?

Comment: `x[1]='\0';` is undefined behavior. You only allocated one `char`, then attempted to treat it as an array of two.

Comment: I did that because whenever I used the char without the null, it would output the character but with junk values as well.
how may i fix this problem?

Comment: Don't pass the pointer to a function that assumes it points at a C string. But better, unless there's some reason to use a pointer, just don't use a pointer in the first place.

Comment: @atta It seems that you didn't read the comment you are replying to. Please read it.

Comment: The problem is that I HAVE to use a pointer character. The problem itself is easy but the topic of pointers is not my strong point. Thus I am stuck here. I shall try your suggestion and get back to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're making 2 mistakes here:

1) You're writing past the end of the array here, since it can only hold 1 character, not 2 like you're attempting to access:

```
char *x=new char[1];
x[0]='R';
x[1]='\0';
```

You're only using one char anyway, so why make it an array? Replace it by:

```
char x = 'R';
```

2) You're not comparing the chars, but the memory addresses they're located at. Of course this won't work. You have to dereference the pointers (i.e. access the stored values) for it to work. Rewrite it like so:

```
if (*data->c == *x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you create the object to look for this way

```
char *x=new char[1];
```

it will never match anything in the list, because you have allocated a new piece of memory. You need to compare what the pointers point to.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are making an illegal write when you are initializing `char x`, by trying to access it's index 1. If you create an array of length `N`, you can access only the indices `[0, N)`. In this case, as you created an array of length 1, you can not access its index 1, as it is out of bounds. You should instead create an array of length 2, if you intend to put the '\0' character.

Secondly, when comparing, you should match the contents to which the `char*` points to, not the pointer itself, which is only an address.

As you are trying to compare a character to another, using their pointers, you should change the innermost if checks (i.e. `if (data->c == x`) with the following:

```
if (*data->c == *x)
```

Thirdly, your code has another bug, related to how deletion of linked list elements is implemented. Basically, you should consider the case where temp2 variable may be nullptr.

Finally, I recommend you look into `std::string`, which may be a better way to represent strings. Alternatively, if your linked list only has single characters, you may simply use character variables, as opposed to allocating a character array for each node in your list.

[Here](https://ideone.com/ICmH7V) is a working version of your code with the updates I mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I would like to use simple character variables as well, however it is compulsory for me to do so.
Also, i tried the string compare method but it would result in run time error.

Comment: I updated my response, and also added a working version of your code with dummy test data to my response. You may want to look into it.

Comment: Thank you, code now works fine. However, if i may ask, what use did if(temp2) have?

Comment: I am simply checking if temp2 is nullptr. To make it more readable you may use `if(temp2 != nullptr)`.

Answer (score 0):

you try to compare string like we compare character reason why it don't work. you can use strcmp instead or use character and not string.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `std::string`?

The struct:

```
struct ll {
    std::string c;
    ll *prev;
    ll *next;
};
```

The string initialization:

```
ll obj;
obj.c = "R";
```

Your `del` function:

```
void del(ll *data, char *val) {
    ll *temp, *temp2;
    bool sm = false;
    std::string x = val;
    while (data != nullptr) {
        if (data->prev == nullptr) {
            if (data->c == x) {
                temp = data;
                data = data->next;
                data->prev = nullptr;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (data->c == x) {
                temp = data;
                data = data->prev;
                data->next = temp->next;
                temp2 = data->next;
                temp2->prev = data;
                delete temp;
            }
        }
        data = data->next;
    }
}
```